# Pass hook or function to a child component

Tags: reactjs

What is the preferred way to change state in React using Hooks?

Option 1: I think this is the more "traditional"

```
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const onInputChange = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value)
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Form onInputChange={onInputChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const Form = ({ onInputChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>

      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type='text'
            onChange={onInputChange}
          />
          <button'>
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Option 2: But I have seen people do this

```
function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Form onInputChange={setInput} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const Form = ({ onInputChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type='text'
            onChange={(e) => {
              onInputChange(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <button>
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

In Option 1 in the App component the logic to change it's state is there.
In Option 2, the logic to change App component is in a child component, right?

If I understand correctly, I think Option 1 makes more sense. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think that the question is necessarily about React. I think it's more about API design in general. Do you need to access other things from the actual change event in the component that uses `Form`? If so, then A. If you're only interested in the text itself, then option B provides a tighter API which lets you rewrite the component entirely - even change the method of input - and still just provide a "strings in, strings out" API.

Answer (score 0):

option 1 is better because we only have to pass the props or data to child component not the logic , Logic must be reside in parent component.